# fetch API, forbidden headers required in OpenAPI

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, swagger-ui, openapi

I'm currently working on creating an OpenAPI file based on documentation to set
up a user-friendly API playground using SwaggerUI. However, I've run into issue
with the `fetch` API as it [restricts certain](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org#forbidden-header-name) headers, including a required
`Date` header for one of the APIs calls.

Is it possible to override this behavior or replace Swagger UI's fetch API with
another compatible solution? Based on my understanding of the documentation, it
appears that `swagger-client` is the only library offering a [custom fetch](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js/blob/master/docs/usage/http-client.md#custom-fetch)
feature, but you can't combine it with SwaggerUI.

API documentation that mention `Date` header https://rest.websupport.sk/docs/v1.intro

Comment: Why do you need this header? Can't you just prefix it, lîke `myapp-date`?

Comment: It's by their backend design. I suggested adding an alternative header like `x-date` to resolve the issue, but the backend team declined due to the API's legacy design.

Comment: I don't really see any way around this.  And, the API should be fixed as well if you expect users to be able to use web-based clients to use this API.  Your API team doesn't have to rewrite the whole API for it as far as I can see.  They could just rewrite the headers at the web server before it reaches the application.  So, you could have `X-Request-Date` or whatever, and then the web server could take it from there while still accepting requests that do have a `Date` request header.

Comment: What @Brad said. Another reason to use a different header name is that the [HTTP spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#field.date) says the `Date` header in requests must be in the format `Date: Mon, 03 Jul 2023 07:58:02 GMT`, whereas the API in question seems to expect `Date: 2023-07-03T07:54:09+00:00`. This means the API is not HTTP-compliant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of version `v5.1.0`, there is no built-in capability to override
the behavior of Swagger UI's fetch API or replace it with another compatible
fetch API.

[Currently](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/src/core/plugins/swagger-js/index.js#L15),
the `swagger-client` library is initialized and wrapped only for the `preFetch`
and `postFetch` options, limiting its customization possibilities.

```
// swagger-ui/core/plugins/swagger-js/index.js
// ...
import Http, { makeHttp, serializeRes } from "swagger-client/es/http"

export default function({ configs, getConfigs }) {
  return {
    fn: {
      fetch: makeHttp(Http, configs.preFetch, configs.postFetch),
      buildRequest,
      execute,
      resolve: makeResolve
    }
    // ...
  }
}
```

By making this dependency
[configurable](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js/blob/master/docs/usage/http-client.md#custom-fetch),
it could open up the potential for replacing the default fetch API behavior in
Swagger UI and allowing the required `Date` header and other headers to be used
as needed.

I'll update this post if I manage to submit a pull request for this feature request.

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out, certain HTTP headers are restricted by the fetch API for security reasons, and `Date` is one of them. Probably because those headers are controlled by the user agent to ensure reliable behavior.

You might consider modifying the API (if you have control over it) so it does not require this header. Instead of relying on a `Date` header sent by the client (which can be unreliable anyway because it is dependent on the client's clock), the API could generate the date server-side.

(Or... [Swagger UI](https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-ui/) is open source and could be forked to make modifications!).

But I suppose you do *not* have control over the original API.

### Middleware layer:

In that case, another (more) possible workaround would be to use a middleware layer, like a proxy server, which injects this header just before forwarding the request to the actual API. That would be transparent to the client-side code, and you could use any client you want, including `fetch` or `swagger-client`.

It does add complexity to your overall setup, and might not always be feasible due to the operational overhead of maintaining such a server, and potential CORS issues. But it could be worth testing.

Install necessary packages: `npm install express axios cors`

And create an Express server (`server.js`) that acts as a proxy for your API. Run it with `node server.js.`

```js
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(cors()); // enable CORS for all requests
app.use(express.json()); // for parsing application/json

// Replace with the base URL of your actual API
const API_URL = 'https://rest.websupport.sk/';

// Function to convert ISO date string to HTTP date format
// Making the date compliant with the HTTP/1.1 specification (RFC 7231)
// Example: "Wed, 16 Jun 2021 17:38:29 GMT"
function convertToHttpDate(isoDateString) {
  const date = new Date(isoDateString);
  return date.toUTCString();
}

app.all('*', async (req, res) => {
  const { originalUrl, method, headers, body } = req;
  
  // Remove the 'host' header as axios sets it automatically
  delete headers['host'];
  
  // Rename and reformat the 'x-request-date' header to 'date'
  if (headers['x-request-date']) {
    headers['date'] = convertToHttpDate(headers['x-request-date']);
    delete headers['x-request-date'];
  }

  try {
    const response = await axios({
      method,
      url: `${API_URL}${originalUrl}`,
      headers,
      data: body,
    });

    res.status(response.status).send(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      console.log(error.response.data);
      console.log(error.response.status);
      console.log(error.response.headers);
      res.status(error.response.status).send(error.response.data);
    } else if (error.request) {
      console.log(error.request);
      res.sendStatus(500);
    } else {
      console.log('Error', error.message);
      res.sendStatus(500);
    }
  }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Proxy server running on http://localhost:3000');
});
```

That server listens to all incoming requests (`app.all('*'...)`), modifies headers as needed, and forwards the requests to the actual API. Responses from the API are then sent back to the original client.

Then, in your front-end JavaScript code using `fetch` or SwaggerUI, you can replace `Date` with `X-Request-Date`:

Front-end JavaScript code (`client.js`):

```js
fetch('http://localhost:3000/your-api-endpoint', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-Request-Date': new Date().toISOString() // Replaced 'Date' with 'X-Request-Date'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    // Your request body here
  })
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error:', error);
});
```

That client-side code would be run in the context of a web page, where it makes requests to the proxy server (which in turn makes requests to the actual API).

Do replace `'http://localhost:3000/your-api-endpoint'` with your actual API endpoint.

That approach can be used as a workaround until the API is fixed to be HTTP-compliant.